# jQuery Validate is not working

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

It's my first time using jQuery Validation and I'm running into issues. This is my form's HTML:

```
<form id="signup" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="sr-only" for="emailAddress">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailAddress" placeholder="Enter email" data-required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="sr-only" for="emailAddressConfirm">Confirm Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailAddressConfirm" placeholder="Confirm email" data-required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" data-required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="sr-only" for="passwordConfirm">Confirm Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordConfirm" placeholder="Confirm Password" data-required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
          </form>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
$("form#signup").on("submit", function(){
    $("form#signup").validate({
        rules: {
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            passwordConfirm: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#password"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            passwordConfirm: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I've copied the example code off the official website but modified the input field ID's. I am unsure why it is not working. (I'm only trying to get the password fields validation correctly, as I can replicate the code for the email inputs from that).

Comment: In addition to requiring the name attribute as mentioned in the answer below, you also do not need to wrap the validate call in `$("form#signup").on("submit", function(){}`

Comment: @Sparky, not according to the documentation, demos, and hundreds of sites I've used it on.

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/  First page, first bit of code, only calls `$("#commentForm").validate();` does not wrap it in an onsubmit function

Comment: @WheatBeak, YES... I thought you were arguing the opposite.  I missed the `submit` handler in the OP's code!  Adding it to my answer now!

Comment: I think you may have read my comment wrong, I said you do **NOT** need to wrap in an onsubmit function.

Comment: @WheatBeak, yes, missed the "not" in your comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) You're missing the `name` attributes from all of the relevant `input` elements. This is absolutely required in order for this plugin to operate properly.

[Documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-markup-recommendations):

> *The `name` attribute is "required" for input elements, **the validation plugin doesn't work without** it.*

Although not stated, the `name` attributes must also be unique as this is how the plugin keeps track of all validated form elements.

---

2) Absolutely, do NOT wrap your call to `.validate()` within a `submit` or `click` handler.  Simply call it on document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("form#signup").validate({ // initialize plugin on your form
        ....
```

The `.validate()` method is only used to *initialize* the plugin and the `click` event of the submit is captured and intercepted automatically.

---

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/L7q7oapc/**

Notice that you do not need to duplicate the same rules on the second password field.  Since it **must** always match the first, these are superfluous.

```
$("form#signup").validate({
    rules: {
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        passwordConfirm: {
            equalTo: "password" // 'name' of other field
        }
    }
```

---

Please refer to the sample code and tips on [the SO Tag Wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info).

Comment: Perfect - What a rookie mistake I have made! Thank you for your swift response :)